# How should I handle auto-refreshing a token?

Tags: react-native, jwt

I'm trying to automatically refresh a JWT within a react native mobile application. A pretty straightforward way of doing this is to use a `setTimeout()` where you calculate how long you need to wait until the token expires. Typically in my application this is going to be about a day.

However doing this in react native gives you a warning linking to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981.

I'm totally OK with my token only being refreshed when the application is in the foreground, what concerns me more is the comment about performance. I'm wondering if there a better practise for handling token refreshing that I'm not aware of? Or in this instance should I be ignoring this warning?

[image: warning]

Comment: Maybe you could watch for your app state when it comes to the foreground instead of setting a timeout?

Comment: @IanVasco that could result in quite a lot of requests that are un-needed is the only thing. Something I specifically want to avoid

Comment: Of course it would be needed to add a bare logic before sending the request. Simply calculate the elapsed time and decide whether or not to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

When you successfully grab the token, add the time to state. When the app state becomes active, grab a new token if the current time is > the stored time plus one day.